# how to read a text file with spaces android java

Tags: java, android, string, inputstream

how do i read a text file with spaces into an int array when i know my file contains

> "22 23 29 1 "

and such

```
private String readFromFile() {

    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("mywords.txt");

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

i used this for read till now

Comment: once you have read your line, split the string using `" "` regex (space) and then parse your substrings to int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `"22 23 29 1 "` i.e Integers with a space try following code:

```
String ret="22 23 29 1 ";
ret=ret.trim();
String tok[]=ret.split(" ");
for(String s:tok) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

**Output :**

```
22
23
29
1
```

If you require you can parse `string` to `integer` using `Integer.parseInt()` .

Comment: it was an exmple i gonna do a file that accamulated ints like that and everytime i open my app i want it to read this file and gime me the int array of this file about what you wrote can u explain to me abit what it does and if its what i need

Comment: Say `ret` is holding the data read from file and is of the format `22 23 29 1`, then the code I wrote would get you each value separately in case you require further computations.

Comment: Overall the dig is to read the whole string altogether and split it as I mentioned.

Comment: i dont get whats going on you make a string array called tok and put ret.split makes tok into an array of the ret? it know alone what the length? you dont need to define? what does s:tok do?

Comment: tnx it works i just dont get how the : work i saw in net about the ? and : together not alone

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Scanner`.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter(" ");
```

and than you can use the functions like `hasNext()` and `next()` to check and read next word.
What you can do is create a `ArrayList` of `Integers` and parse as you get `next()`.

Something like (this is just a pseudo-code)

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    read = scanner.next();
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(read));
}
return list;
```

Answer (score 0):

make a call to `split(" ")` on returned String you will get String array. Typecast as per your usage.

Comment: can you give me a code its my 1st time reading a file i not know much